# How to use XML layout as drawable image

Tags: android, gallery

I would like to add an XML `Layout` as `drawable image` for `GalleryView`. Is it possible? here is the scenario, I'm having one `Layout` in my application. I would like to use images for my gallery, those images exactly looking like the XML `layout`(but background and some other views color will be different). So instead of creating multiple images for gallery, I want to use these xml layout as `drawables` in Gallery view. Is it possible,? If so how to do that? please help me out friends.

Comment: create xml file under drawable folder and you only can give features in it or can create selector and use that file as a background of gallery as android:background="@drawable/xmlfile"

Comment: @Raveesh you can capture whole layout as a bitmap and then you can use that bitmap as images. But for this approach you have to give different background & etc.. each time when you capture different layout bitmap.

Comment: @AkashG I think you are talking same as Nirali's answer, Am i right ?

Comment: yes @Raveesh this is what i was trying to say

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my layout is not selector button, or a simple view. its an layout having more number of child layouts, and setting texts, icons on the views.

Comment: @Android Coader thats good idea. let me try this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

See i have create XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/always_over" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/always_over" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/always_over" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/always" android:state_enabled="true"/>

</selector>
```

And then set in Button

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAlways"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/always_xml" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my layout is not selector button, or a simple view. its an layout having more number of child layouts, and setting texts, icons on the views.